# How to check if a Django model object gets locked?

Tags: django, django-models, locking

Is there any way to check if a Django model object is fetched using select_for_update()?
Although 'locked' property in the following code does not exists actually, I want one like this.

```
with atomic():
   unlocked_obj = SomeModel.objects.get(pk=123)
   unlocked_obj.locked  # False

   locked_obj = SomeModel.objects.select_for_update().get(pk=123)
   locked_obj.locked  # True
```

Answer (score 4):

The only way to check that is by including "select_for_update(**nowait = True**)", if it is locked, Django raise a DatabaseError.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update

Answer (score -4):

Open 2 django shells

#### Shell1

```
with atomic():
    obj = SomeModel.objects.select_for_update().get(id=123)
    import time; time.sleep(10)
```

#### Shell2

```
with atomic():
    obj = SomeModel.objects.get(id=123)
    obj.save()
```

`obj.save()` instruction in Shell2 should pause until Shell1 doesn't come out of the transaction.